# KFAS: Negative variances and huge Std Errors

Tags: r, data-modeling, kalman-filter

I am trying to fit a Marketing Mix Model and run into the following problem:

> *Warning message:*
>   *In KFS(model) :
>    Possible error in diffuse filtering: Negative variances in Pinf, check the >model or try changing the tolerance parameter tol or P1/P1inf of the model.*

Below is a reproducible sample code with more detail.

The goal is to develop a tool to optimize marketing mix
Below x1(t), x2(t), x3(t) are investments into 3 marketing channelsat time t
y(t) is the sales at time t

We want to use Kalman Filter approach:
y(t) = alpha + lambda * y(t-1) + beta1 * x1(t) + beta2 * x2(t) + beta3 * x3(t) +
        beta12 * x1(t) * x2(t) + beta13 * x1(t) * x3(t) + beta23 * x2(t) * x3(t) + N(0, sigma)

In order to:
 i.   deduce sales attributed to each channel x1(t), x2(t), x3(t)
 ii.  their synergies x1 * x2, x1 * x3, x2 * x3
 iii. carry over sales yCO(t) = y(t-1)

We use KFAS package 
 https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/KFAS/index.html

Below is a simple reproducible example where we:
 1. Simulate x1(t), x2(t), x3(t)
 2. Set input parameter values used for sales simulation
    b1, b2, b12, ..., b23, lambdaà, and sigma
 3. Use simulated y(t), x1(t), x2(t), x3(t) to fit the model
 4. Compare estimated coefficient with input values b1, b2,...

```
library(KFAS)

library(dplyr)

sigma<-50

set.seed(1)
x1<-1000 + rnorm(n = 100,mean = 0,sd = 100) + rnorm(100, 0, sigma)
x2<-rep(0, 100)
x2[sort(which(1:100%%6==0))]<-500 
x3<-300+100*sin(1:100%%12/12*pi) + rnorm(100, 0, sigma)


#Operationalize with SQRT
x1<-sqrt(x1)
x2<-sqrt(x2)
x3<-sqrt(x3)

#Set input parameters fro simulation
lambda0<-0.5
b1 <- 3 
b2 <- 4
b3 <- 5

b12 <- 0.3
b13 <- 0.2
b23 <- 0.1


y_s <- 
   b1 * x1 + 
   b2 * x2 +
   b3 * x3 +
   b12 * x1 * x2 +
   b13 * x1 * x3 +
   b23 * x2 * x3 + 
   rnorm(100, sd = sigma)

# function to account for carry over term
# y(t) = lambda * y(t-1) + y_s(t) , where
# y_s(t) = b1 * x1 + b2 * x2 + b3 * x3 + Synergy terms
getCarryOver<-function(t,
                       y_s,
                       lambda)
{
  if (t==1) return(y_s[1])
  else lambda*getCarryOver(t-1,y_s,lambda) + y_s[t] 
}


# Add Carry Over term
y<-vector('numeric',100)
for (i in 1:100){
  y[i]<-getCarryOver(i,y_s,lambda0)
}

yCO=dplyr::lag(y)
yCO[1]=0

if (!identical(y[-1],y_s[-1]+lambda0*yCO[-1]))  
stop('identical(y,y_s+lambda0*yCO)')

model <- SSModel(y ~ SSMregression(~ x1 + 
                                     x2 + 
                                     x3 + 
                                     x1*x2 + 
                                     x1*x3 +
                                     x2*x3 +
                                     yCO
                                   , Q = diag(NA,1)), H = NA)
fit <- fitSSM(model, inits = c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0), method = "BFGS")

model <- fit$model
model$Q
model$H
out <- KFS(model)

print(out)
```

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't fully answer your question but this is too long for a comment...

You are not creating the same model you have formulated in before the codes. By defining Q=NA you are actually stating that the first coefficient x1 should be time varying with unknown variance. And then in the `fitSSM` call you are giving too many initial values so you don't notice the error (only Q and H need numerical estimation by fitSSM, the coeffients for x1 etc are directly estimated by Kalman filter). I admit there is probably few checks missing here which would warn user accordingly. `SSMregression` function is only needed if you have time-varying regression coefficients or complex multivariate models, here you can just write `SSModel(y~ x1*x2 + x1*x3 + x2*x3 + yCO, H=NA)` (the main effects are automatically included as in `lm`).

I would also check the carryover term calculations, just to be sure that you actually generate your data correctly.

If you still get errors, it could be that you have really high multicollinearity that you need to modify the prior for first time step, ie set `model$P1inf[] <- 0` (removes the diffuse initialization) and set `diag(model$P1)` to something moderate like 100, (prior variance of the coefficients).

Actually if you are using the the formulation you suggest (all x's and yC0 as simple explanatory variable) then you should get identical results with `lm`. And running your code with `lm` I get same apparently wrong results:

```
> model <- SSModel(y~ x1*x2 + x1*x3 + x2*x3 + yCO, H=NA)
> 
> fit <- fitSSM(model, inits = 0, method = "BFGS")
> out <- KFS(fit$model)
Warning message:
In KFS(fit$model) :
  Possible error in diffuse filtering: Negative variances in Pinf, check the model or try changing the tolerance parameter tol or P1/P1inf of the model.
> out
Smoothed values of states and standard errors at time n = 100:
             Estimate    Std. Error
(Intercept)  -1.171e+03   1.300e+03
x1            3.782e+01   4.102e+01
x2           -4.395e+00   1.235e+01
x3            7.287e+01   6.844e+01
yCO           5.244e-01   3.396e-02
x1:x2         5.215e-01   3.979e-01
x1:x3        -1.853e+00   2.167e+00
x2:x3         1.671e-01   3.471e-01

> summary(lm(y~ x1*x2 + x1*x3 + x2*x3 + yCO))

Call:
lm(formula = y ~ x1 * x2 + x1 * x3 + x2 * x3 + yCO)

Residuals:
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-137.297  -29.870   -2.214   35.178   87.578 

Coefficients:
              Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept) -1.171e+03  1.300e+03  -0.901    0.370    
x1           3.782e+01  4.102e+01   0.922    0.359    
x2          -4.395e+00  1.235e+01  -0.356    0.723    
x3           7.287e+01  6.844e+01   1.065    0.290    
yCO          5.244e-01  3.396e-02  15.445   <2e-16 ***
x1:x2        5.215e-01  3.979e-01   1.311    0.193    
x1:x3       -1.853e+00  2.167e+00  -0.855    0.395    
x2:x3        1.671e-01  3.471e-01   0.481    0.631    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 50.25 on 92 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:   0.88, Adjusted R-squared:  0.8709 
F-statistic: 96.43 on 7 and 92 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```

So I think you have some issues with generating your example data, or in the model formulation.